# contenteditable Only allow defined tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a contenteditable div that users are able to write a small amount of text and I chose to use contentediable div over textarea because I would like them to be able to insert images and links if needed. The issue is I want to strip all other formation from this div in. I would like to only allow certain tags within this div.

What I need help with:

1.) Paste - When pasting it will copy formatting and insert that into the div, is there a way to force paste as plain text?

2.) restrict user from hitting "ctrl+b" to bold text, some for underline, and italicize.

Here is the following code I have and it does work but it seems that if you hit "ctrl+c" to paste and start typing your cursor is behind what you pasted.

```
$(this).find("*").not("a,img").each(function() { 
  $(this).replaceWith(this.innerHTML); 
});
```